# Cannot kill Node JS Process

Tags: node.js

I am facing a strange problem as below. 
I run the command: 
ps aux | grep node
when I try to kill that process, it says – No such process. I don't know why it gives such message. Please suggest.

```
[root@ashst94006 loc-2.0.3]# ps aux | grep node
root 25327 0.0 0.0 103236 852 pts/0 S+ 05:35 0:00 grep node
[root@ashst94006 loc-2.0.3]# kill 25327
-bash: kill: (25327) – No such process
[root@ashst94006 loc-2.0.3]# ps aux | grep node
root 5512 0.0 0.0 103236 848 pts/0 S+ 05:35 0:00 grep node
[root@ashst94006 loc-2.0.3]# kill 5512
-bash: kill: (5512) – No such process
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the `grep node` itself, which cannot be killed, as it is already stopped after your command has been evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **kill all node process** you should use command as below

```
 killall -9 node
```

if any node process is currently working state then that process will be killed after running this command.